# How to enable MacBook to recognize android devices

Tags: android

For Windows, Google provides USB Driver but Google USB Driver is not compatible with Mac OS and I read that anything did not need to Mac OS and Linux.

I've already set "USB Debugging ON" on my android device.

Followings are my development environment.

```
OS: Mac OS 10.6.8
Android Device: Google Nexus S 
Android OS: 4.0.3
IDE: Eclipse SDK 3.7.2
```

The application I make uses camera, so I need to debug with devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It should just work.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

I would imagine there's something else going on.  Plug your phone in and try listing it from the command line:

```
$ adb devices
```

If it's not, try restarting the adb server:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

After you restart the server, if the device still isn't listed, unplug then plug in again to a different USB port.  Failing that, restart the system.

Once the device appears when using the `$ adb devices` command, try obtaining a shell:

```
$adb shell
```

If that fails, I would make sure your SKD is up to date as well as the ADT Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I tried to do all, and finally my application is installed into the android device. 
But nothing is displayed on "List of devices attached"(adb devices).
Is it normal??

Comment: All that I have to add is make sure you have the latest revision of the Android SDK (not just Eclipse SDK).  Otherwise, check your physical cable and check the phone on another machine.  If it doesn't work on another machine where other devices do work (and with the cable that works) then you might have a bad port or firmware or something -- in which case you should contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Also make sure developer mode is enabled on your device

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues too and it seemed like it was related to the USB hubs not working properly. Trying [resetting your PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your Android device needs to be in Developer Mode.

Go to **Settings > About phone** and **tap many times on the Build-Number**.

See here: http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/09/disable-sms-text-google-hangouts/